# Move content DB MOSS 2007

Tags: 2007

They used to create a new content database each time a new site collection is created. Now when I tried to upload a picture file it says that the file cannot be uploaded and log file had nothing on about the issue.

So I checked back to the SQL server and the sql server has 0 GB left on the drive. I guess the problem is because of the numerous content database that are being created. When a user tried to upload an image file to a picture library, it canot upload. I tried to upload a text file it did upload, but a word file was not uploaded.

I would be grateful if I could get a solution to fix this problem. I tried to upload the same word file to another site application and it did upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple really - content is stored in SQL databases so you need to free up space by either removing content from SharePoint (including the recycle bins) or perhaps shrinking DB log files.

In the latter case you should consult your DBA team as shrinking content databases with any regularity is not generally considered a good idea.

I would check:

- Whether any SQL log (.ldf)  files are using a particularly large
  amount of space and consider shrinking them.
- Check the recovery model for each database to ensure it is aligned with your RPO requirements (e.g. has it been left in "FULL" recovery
  mode by mistake)
- Versioning settings for document libraries within large content databases

Obviously going forward you need to determine a capacity plan to allow your environment to scale out - and perhaps work out why this wasn't done in the first place.

Comment: does merging different DB's into one provide free space? Like moving from their specific DB into 1 specific content DB per Web App?
 
And how do we check whether it is in "FULL" recovery mode or not?

Comment: In a word, "No" answers your first question. The only way of reducing space would be to remove content or shrink the DB log files. This link describes how to view the DB recovery mode - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189272(v=sql.105).aspx. Make sure you thoroughly review the considerations prior to changing it as it may impact your recovery point objectives.